# How to add an Artifact Registry using "help repo add"?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, google-artifact-registry

After authenticating to GCP using `gcloud` (which seems to store credentials in the Docker configuration) I am able to push a Helm chart to my Artifact Registry:

```
$ helm push my-appl-1.0.0.tgz oci://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing/charts
Pushed: us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing/charts/my-appl:1.0.0
Digest: sha256:321ac1f93e52fc741e81c03a8509255fc34275ac52edb7a3677a459f6f80a6cd
```

However, I cannot get `helm repo add` to work. I have tried this:

```
$ helm repo add gcp-ar https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing
Error: looks like "https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error unmarshaling JSON: while decoding JSON: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type repo.IndexFile
```

I also tried these with the same bad results:

```
helm repo add gcp-ar oci://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing
helm repo add gcp-ar oci://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing/charts
helm repo add gcp-ar https://us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-gcp-project/docker-testing/charts
```

How do I get an Artifact Registry Helm repo registered locally using "helm repo add"?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to treat OCI *registries* like traditional Helm *repositories*. They are simply two different types of indexed storage. You can use simple commands like `helm registry login` and `helm push oci://...` with OCI registries. They came from the Docker world. You can use `helm repo` commands to manage classical repositories.